# Unable to pass parameters from view to controller in MVC5

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to use an ActionLink to pass an instance of a ViewModel from my view to a controller. However, the ViewModel is always null when it reaches the controller.

ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Begin Test", "TakeTest", new { vm = Model }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult TakeTest(QuizViewModel vm) {
        ViewBag.Title = vm.vmTest.TestName;

        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        vm.Student = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == userId);

        vm.Attempt = db.Attempts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Student == vm.Student && a.Test == vm.vmTest);
        if (vm.vmTest.AttemptsAllowed > 0 && vm.Attempt.Count >= vm.vmTest.AttemptsAllowed) {
                return View();
        }
        vm.Attempt.Count++;
        if (vm.QuestionList == null) {
            vm.QuestionList = db.Questions.Where(q => q.TID == vm.vmTest.ID).ToList();
        }

        Random r = new Random();
        int randQid = r.Next(0, vm.QuestionList.Count - 1);
        vm.ShowQuestion = vm.QuestionList[randQid];
        vm.QuestionList.Remove(vm.ShowQuestion);
        vm.Asets = db.AnswerSets.Where(a => a.Question == vm.ShowQuestion).ToList();


        return View(vm);

    }
```

Comment: Assuming `QuizViewModel` contains only simple properties, then its `@Html.ActionLink("Begin Test", "TakeTest", Model, new { ... })`. But do not do this - just pass the ID of the model and get it again in the controller method

Comment: Looking at the code in your controller, your model does contain properties which are complex objects so that is not possible (which is fortunate since it would almost certainly throw an exception because of the query string limit)